Unreasonably small generalization error produced by untrained DNN
Im currently trying to train a DNN for a regression task. The goal is predict 2 QoIs given 4 input features. For training and validation I use 40 training patterns obtained by LHS, with a split 80-20. After I train a model I use it to predict 300 new unseen samples randomly obtained from normal distribution and I calculate the rmse (between predictions and real results) of the two QoIs. I use 2 instances of standard scaler(), one for the X (inputs) and one for the y(outputs). The same two scaler instances are used for the prediction of the 300 samples. The first one to scale the inputs before providing them to the model and the second one to (inverse) scale back the models prediction into their corresponding magnittudes. (I will mention the issue only for the one QoI since the exact same thing validates for the 2nd).
The  rmse values on the 300 I have seen so far is something around 2 to 4.5 10^(-4). The paradox here is that, once,just for checking, I used my compiled model BEFORE training, to predict the 300 and see what the RMSE would look like. My brain tells me that this error should be something very far away than the values I have seen so far since the model is completely untrained. The results (for different seedstates aka initializations) are also around 510^(-4) just super slighly worst than the results obtained from the trained model. This seems to me completely nonsense and I am trying to understand where in my python code I must have made a mistake that could lead me here. PS1: The problem is that I am gettin a very "small" generalization error from a completely untrained DNN used in regression. PS2:The rsme is being calculated after the models predictions are scaled back to their corresponding magnitudes.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
